# How to read in a text file without reading in # characters

Tags: java

I want to read in a given text file and in the text file, it contains # character to separate mountain name, country, and altitude.I want to only read in everything except the # characters.  For example:

```
A-1 Peak#United States#12377 <-- from the text file
A-1 Peak United States 12377 <-- read in only
```

I know I have to use the String split method, but I am not sure if how I am doing this is correct.

```
private List<String> readFile(String fileName)
    {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {

            String[] parts = line.split("#");
            String part1 = parts[0]; 
            String part2 = parts[1]; 
            String part3 = parts[2];
                records.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return records;
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually encountering any problem?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are you receiving an error message? What is your desired output? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: OP - you should refer this Q to codereview community. But yes - your approach is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      line  = line.replaceAll("#"," "); 
      records.add(line);
}
```

Comment: nope. the # separates different values. His approach is ok.He probably needs to know where one starts and another ends

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      line.split("#");
      records.add(line);
}
```

line.split returns an array of Strings broken up by the delimiter (ie '#'). You probably want to use that array instead of the whole string, right?

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
       String[] split = line.split("#");
       for (int I = 0; I < split.length; I++) {
           //do some processing
       }
}
```

Also, it is very bad practice / dangerous to use `catch (Exception) {`. You should catch a more explicit Exception, like IO exception

Comment: Thank You, I changed it to IOException

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `split()` method, rather use `replaceAll("#", " ")` to replace `#` as shown below:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   line = replaceAll("#", " ");
    records.add(line);
}
```

Also, I suggest you close the `BufferedReader` object in the `finally` block or use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to use the String split method, but I am not sure if how
>   I am doing this is correct.

if you wish to proceed with the `split()` method, then you could use `StringBuilder` to append all the data back together before adding to the `records` list.

```
String[] parts = line.split("#");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(parts[0]+ " "); 
builder.append(parts[1]+ " "); 
builder.append(parts[2]); 
records.add(builder.toString());
```

or simply:

```
records.add(line.replace("#"," "));
```